# Get body of error response with Spring Reactive Elasticsearch Client

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using Spring Data Elasticsearch to get some aggregations, and I'm trying to use the `ReactiveElasticsearchClient`. I'm getting a 500 error from Elasticsearch, but can't figure out how to get the body of the response so that I can debug what's wrong with my request. Here's what I have so far:

```
    final Flux<Aggregation> resp = client.aggregate(request -> {
        final SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(query)).size(0)
                .aggregation(AggregationBuilders.composite("report", compositeValueBuilders));

        request.indices(index).source(sourceBuilder);

    });

    resp.doOnError(throwable -> {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }).log().doOnEach(signal -> {
        if (signal.hasError()) {
            signal.getThrowable().printStackTrace();
        } else {
            final Aggregation agg = signal.get();
            System.out.println(agg.getType());
            System.out.println(agg.getClass());
            System.out.println(agg.getName());
        }
    }).blockLast();
```

With trace logging enabled for org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.WIRE, the request body is logged, but the log line for the response is just this:

> 2020-06-09 14:12:46.625 TRACE 19999 --- [or-http-epoll-1] o.s.data.elasticsearch.client.WIRE       : [4ed5a037] Received raw response: 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

I'm getting the following stack trace. I can see the `ElasticsearchStatusException`, but I don't see anything I can do with the `Signal` object to get the response body.

```
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: POST request to /<index name>/_search returned error code 500.
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient.handleServerError(DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient.java:809) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient.readResponseBody(DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient.java:760) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient.lambda$sendRequest$22(DefaultReactiveElasticsearchClient.java:680) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:4.0.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:156) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1755) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:385) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:173) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:213) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:845) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:845) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2317) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onSubscribeInner(MonoFlatMapMany.java:143) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:182) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryPredicate$RetryPredicateSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryPredicate.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:156) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpIOHandlerObserver.onStateChange(HttpClientConnect.java:428) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.7.RELEASE.jar:0.9.7.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:514) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.7.RELEASE.jar:0.9.7.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onStateChange(PooledConnectionProvider.java:536) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.7.RELEASE.jar:0.9.7.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onStateChange(PooledConnectionProvider.java:427) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.7.RELEASE.jar:0.9.7.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:562) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.7.RELEASE.jar:0.9.7.RELEASE]
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.7.RELEASE.jar:0.9.7.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286) ~[netty-handler-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311) ~[netty-codec-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:425) ~[netty-codec-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.49.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.49.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.49.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.49.Final.jar:4.1.49.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Tl;dr: How do I get the response body of an error response when using the Spring `ReactiveElasticsearchClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [activate the logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.logging) by setting the logging level of

```
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.WIRE
```

to *trace* level. This logs what is sent and received, especially in the case of errors (excerpt from the implementation):

```
private <T> Publisher<? extends T> readResponseBody(String logId, Request request, ClientResponse response,
        Class<T> responseType) {

    // ...

    if (response.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {

        ClientLogger.logRawResponse(logId, response.statusCode());
        return handleServerError(request, response);
    }

    if (response.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {

        ClientLogger.logRawResponse(logId, response.statusCode());
        return handleClientError(logId, request, response, responseType);
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Edit:**

sorry, my fault, should have seen that the response body is not logged.

What you could do is use an intercepting proxy that monitors the traffic between your application and Elasticsearch. There's the [OWASP ZAP proxy](https://owasp.org/www-project-zap/) and the [Burp Suite Community edition](https://portswigger.net/burp/communitydownload). Both applications start as a proxy on port 8080, so you either need to configure your application to listen on a different port (`server.port` in the application properties, I use for example 9090 for my test app) or change the proxy port. Besides that you need to configure the proxy in your app, I have the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ReactiveRestClientConfig extends AbstractReactiveElasticsearchConfiguration {
    @Override
    public ReactiveElasticsearchClient reactiveElasticsearchClient() {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder() //
            .connectedTo("localhost:9200") //
            .withProxy("localhost:8080")
            .build();
        return ReactiveRestClients.create(clientConfiguration);

    }
}
```

The when accessing you application, the traffic to Elasticsearch goes through the proxy where you can see the requests and responses.

Comment: I can see my request body, but for the response it just says "[4ed5a037] Received raw response: 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"

Comment: see my updated answer, I hope that helps, feel free to ask for more info if necessary

Comment: Unfortunate that that's the only option - too many hoops to jump through for me, especially for a production system, so I'll be switching to `RestHighLevelClient`, but this is definitely useful for anyone else trying to make the reactive client work.

Comment: using the same query on the non-reactive stack should give you the same error, as a 500 is coming from Elasticsearch

Comment: I will add a ticket to have the response body logged as well in the error case